# Google charts; Uncaught Error: Not an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, google-visualization

I'm trying to load a Google Chart using Ajax and for some reason the data being passed back says its not an array.

Here is the Javascript on the page that I wish for the charts to display:

```
<script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

    function drawCharts(){

        // Each chart function

        $.get('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'usage'}, function(data){

            if(data){
                initGoogleChart(data)
            }
        });
    }

    function initGoogleChart(data){
        var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

        var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('terms-table'));
        chart.draw(tableData, options);

    }

</script>
```

And on the charts_ajax.php file there is this:

```
if ($_GET['a'] == "usage") {

   $arrTableData = array([
       ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
       ['Work',     11],
       ['Eat',      2],
       ['Commute',  2],
       ['Watch TV', 2],
       ['Sleep',    7]
   ]);

    echo $arrTableData;
}
```

When I console.log($arrTableData) I get:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
   array(6) {
      [0]=>
     array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Task"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Hours per Day"

 // etc etc..
```

So can you tell me why it is saying that there is not an array and why it isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update your php function like this:

```
if ($_GET['a'] == "usage") {

    $arrTableData = array(
        array('Task',     'Hours per Day'),
        array('Work',     11),
        array('Eat',      2),
        array('Commute',  2),
        array('Watch TV', 2),
        array('Sleep',    7)
    );

    echo json_encode($arrTableData);
}
```

try this in your javascript function:

```
function initGoogleChart(data) {

    var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(data));

    ...

}
```

Comment: I am now getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a

Comment: what's the complete error message? is it on PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: javascript and its: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T ?nav-filter=all:1631
initGoogleChart ?nav-filter=all:1631
(anonymous function) ?nav-filter=all:1616
c jquery-combined.js?12:8
p.fireWith jquery-combined.js?12:8
k jquery-combined.js?12:10
r

Comment: I have updated it and now I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T  - WTFH

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json_encode` function in PHP:

```
echo json_encode($arrTableData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the two other answers.  Use `echo json_encode($arrTableData);` to output the array as a JSON-encoded string, and use `var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(data));` to decode the JSON as a javascript array.

Comment: this is now the charts_ajax.php if ($_GET['a'] == "usage") {

        $arrTableData = array([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work',     11],
            ['Eat',      2],
            ['Commute',  2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        echo json_encode($arrTableData);
    } - still same error

Comment: Did you change the javascript as well?